# What is a simple way to split a long code while keep it on the same webpage?

Tags: html

I am currently editing a webpage I made using Tumblr and it has told me that I have exceeded the 500k character limit. I have nearly one million characters, so I want to take a part of my code, put it onto somewhere else and import it onto my same webpage with a laconic code.

Can anyone recommend me a simple way to do this so that it can all stay on the same page? I have attempted using the iframe feature for larger sections of my website, but it does not perform how I want it to with my CSS. I have seen online that you can use HTML5 imports, but I have seen this feature is highly discouraged and it does not work across all browsers. Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: What in the world are you doing that required *one megabyte* of code...?

Comment: Hi there. I am making a celebrity archive of over 3000 photos. I am using thumbnail images for all of the images, so there is a lot of code for that reason.

Comment: Have you thought about maybe just having, say, 20 images per page?